# All leading meaning in Hotel Transylvania

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

I am learning English, and I try to see movies for listening and vocabulary.

I have started to see Hotel Transylvania movie and I could not understand a dialog:

> **All leading to** my daughter's birthday extravaganza tommorrow

I knew all of words but I could not understand the sentence meaning​ completely.

Comment: Here is a road that leads to my house. Here is another road that leads to my house. Are _all_ roads leading to my house? If you look up _lead_ in a dictionary, my sentences should be clear. If your sentence is still not clear, could you explain what confuses you? Maybe you should provide some more context, because _all_ refers to something that was mentioned earlier, and you are not telling us what was mentioned earlier.

Comment: All roads lead to Rome.

Comment: My problem is that the sentence does not have a verb, so I can not understand its meaning.

Comment: Multiple online sources of the transcript for the movie in question give the complete line as "I have personally designed a spectacular schedule of events, all leading to my daughter's birthday extravaganza tomorrow." If these sources are accurate, the phrase you quote is not a sentence but a clause subordinate to the noun _events_ (or to the noun _schedule_); such a clause does not require a verb. The sense of the clause is that all of the aforementioned events (or all of the aforementioned schedule) lead (or leads) up to the birthday extravaganza.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poser misunderstood a line of dialog, and is only focused on the second half of a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the person is trying to say that there have been some things/some events that were going to "cause" his daughter's birthday extravaganza the next day.